# Call explicit constructor/destructor with traits in templatized function

Tags: c++, typedef, destructor, traits, delete-operator

I'm trying to call explicit constructor/destructor with traits in templatized function.

```
template <int i>
struct Traits
{
};
template <>
struct Traits<1>
{
  typedef Foo type_t;
};
template <>
struct Traits<2>
{
  typedef Bar type_t;
};

template <class Traits>
void DoSomething(void* p_in)
{
  typename Traits::type_t* p = reinterpret_cast<typename Traits::type_t*>(p_in);
  // this works.
  new (p) typename Traits::type_t;
  // neither of following two does work.
  p->~typename Traits::type_t();
  p->typename ~Traits::type_t();
}

// call
void* p_in = malloc(BIG_ENOUGH);
DoSomething<Traits<1> >(p_in);
free(p_in);
```

In GCC 4.4.3 with -ansi flag, calling explicit constructor works fine. However, calling explicit destructor does not work, giving following error:

```
error: expected identifier before 'typename'
error: expected ';' before 'typename'
```

I suspect some parentheses or keyword is missing.

**UPDATE**

People ask about why I am doing this... Yes, as expected, I want to use memory pool, and give two functions to clients. Internally it uses a static pointer to the memory pool for malloc/free.

```
template<class Traits>
typename Traits::type_t* memory_pool_new();
template<class Traits>
void memory_pool_delete();
```

Of course this approach has limitations... like only default constructor can be used. I thought about overloading new, but it requires overloading new of all type_t's, and it will change the behavior of existing codes.

Comment: why are you calling destructors??

Comment: What are you trying to do, actually? Trying to call which destructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN site gives this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35xa3368%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> To explicitly call the destructor for an object, `s`, of class
>   `String`, use one of the following statements:
>
> ```
> s.String::~String();     // Nonvirtual call
> ps->String::~String();   // Nonvirtual call
>
> s.~String();       // Virtual call
> ps->~String();     // Virtual call
> ```

So you could try to add a typedef and mimic the above with:

```
typedef typename Traits::type_t TraitsType;

// we now have that p is of TraitsType*
p->TraitsType::~TraitsType(); // nonvirtual call
p->~TraitsType();             // virtual call
```

Comment: Thanks- It works like a charm! I read MSDN, but couldn't think of adding typedef.

Comment: If he's using some kind of memory pool and uses in-place construction, explicitly calling the destructor might be useful.

Comment: @Cubic I see now, but much better to overload class-specific `operator new` then to not confuse clients. `DoSomething` suggests a regular function at work, not some fancy memory allocation.

Comment: Using a typedef inside my template function worked nicely for me to delete the inplace constructed object using the typedef name.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use a local typedef since `typename Traits::type_t` is a bit of a mouthful. If you don't want to do that, then the destructor syntax is:

```
p->Traits::type_t::~type_t();
```

By the way, there's no need to mess around with `reinterpret_cast`; you can simply initialise the typed pointer from the new expression:

```
typename Traits::type_t* p = new (p_in) typename Traits::type_t;
```