# Explicit constructor calls with template are not supported by clang

Tags: c++

Explicit constructor calls are supported by clang (this->ClassName::ClassName())  with -fms-extensions
thanks!

```
template<int k>
class Base {
public:
    int num = 0;
    Base(int sdsd):num(sdsd) {}
    void func(int v) {num = 12 + v;}
};


template <int Ty>
void callA(Base<Ty> *obj){
    (reinterpret_cast< Base<Ty>*>(obj))->Base::Base(1); // error: cannot refer to type member 'Base' in 'Base<99>' with '->'
                                                        // but with MS compiler in windows that's right

    (reinterpret_cast< Base<Ty>*>(obj))->Base::func(1); // ok
}
void callB(void *obj){
    (reinterpret_cast< Base<100>*>(obj))->Base::Base(2);// ok
    (reinterpret_cast< Base<100>*>(obj))->Base::func(1); // ok
}

int main(int argn, char** argc) {
    Base<99> a(0);
    callA(&a);
    callB(&a);
}
```

Comment: What is this?  Calling `reinterpret_cast` to convert to a completely different template instance sounds like undefined behavior to me.  What is the purpose of trying to directly invoke a constructor?  Are you trying to emulate _placement-new_?

Comment: [When to use reinterpret_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast) reinterpret_cast<type>(v) is a forced conversion, such as (type)v, but this conversion often reports errors

Comment: in fact, (reinterpret_cast< Base<Ty>*>(obj)). <=> ((Base<Ty>) (void*) obj)

Comment: Two completely unrelated class template instances are not convertible.  The behavior here I think is either undefined or implementation specific.  I know what `reinterpret_cast` does, and it is NOT there just to get around a fundamental error caused by you attempting something fundamentally dangerous.

Comment: Isn't . ```obj->Base::Base(1); ``` Still error, ```reinterpret_cast ``` is not the point

Comment: Yes.  My point is that using `reinterpret_cast` is not a solution, as you're trying to trick the compiler into thinking it's not an error.

Comment: You sure this has something to do with templates? If I remember correctly, it's simply not allowed by the standard (so MSVC is misbehaving).

Answer (score -1):

ok, I find the solution;just use `new (obj) Base<Ty>(1);`[Call explicit constructor/destructor with traits in templatized function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988209/call-explicit-constructor-destructor-with-traits-in-templatized-function)

Comment: This is called _placement-new_, which I mentioned in my original comment.  However, you cannot do this in your `callB` function, if that's what you think you're doing.  This is _undefined behavior_.  What this does is overwrite the original object, re-using its memory to construct the new object in its place.  The problem here is that the compiler still thinks that `a` is of type `Base<99>` and will use that class's destructor later.  For your trivial example it "works" by chance, but for a real example this is super-duper dangerous. All my comments about `reinterpret_cast` apply.

Comment: To expand on this, it's also an error in `callA`, because you have not used _placement-delete_.  Again, trivial examples "work", but essentially here you have simply overwritten a valid object's memory with that of a newly-constructed object in its stead.  At best, nothing bad happens.  More commonly, you leak memory.  At worst, all hell breaks loose!

Comment: sorry! I did not understand what you mean by "placement-new", everything is normal now  [my code](https://github.com/notify-bibi/TriggerBug/blob/master/src/engine/basic_var.hpp). Thank you, you are correct.